# NSMassFormatter does not return localized values

Tags: ios, localization, ios8, healthkit

I want to use iOS 8's new HealthKit `NSFormatters` to show the weight of a person according to locale. So 80 kgs in Europe should be formatted as `176.36 pounds` in the US, but 80 kg in Europe. 
For this I use the `unitStringFromKilograms` method, which according to the Docs should return:

> A localized string representing the unit. This method selects the correct unit based on the formatter’s locale, the magnitude of the value, and the `forPersonMassUse` property.

However, the following piece of code, on several laptops with multiple locales and `iOS` devices with metric locales, always return 'pounds'.

Is this a bug or did I forget something so obvious that Apple didn't mention it in their docs?

```
import HealthKit

let massFormatter = NSMassFormatter()
massFormatter.forPersonMassUse = true // it doesn't matter if this is false
massFormatter.unitStyle = .Long
var massFormatterUnit = NSMassFormatterUnit.Kilogram

// This unitString SHOULD be according to locale, e.g. kg in Europe, pounds in us.
// instead it always returns 'pounds'
let unitString = massFormatter.unitStringFromKilograms(80, usedUnit: &massFormatterUnit)
```

Comment: Try running this on actual devices with region and language set. The simulator has a tendency to misbehave when it comes to locales.

Comment: I did try it on multiple iOS devices (iPad and iPhone running 8.1), but lb showed up as well. When I set the locale manually in the app, the unit shows up as kg. 
Strange. Anyhoo: thanks for the response!